# Probability of triangles in $G(n, 1/2)$

Tags: probability, graph-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to solve the following problem: Let $G = G(n, \frac{1}{2})$ be a random graph on $n$ vertices, i.e., for each pair of vertices $i, j$, we add the edge $(i, j)$ independently with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Let $T_n$ be the number of triangles (i.e., cycles of length 3) in $G$. I am trying to find $E[T_n]$, the expectation of $T_n$, and $Var[T_n]$, the variance of $T_n$. Then, I need to find a way to prove that with high probability every vertex of $G$ is incident to a triangle (or in other words, let $p_n$ be the probability that for every vertex $i$, there is a triangle in $G$ containing $i$, and then prove that $p_n$ tends to 1 as $n$ tends to infinity.) Any help or suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer I work more generally with $G\left(n,p\right)$ and
under the convention that $\binom{m}{k}=0$ if $k\notin\left\{ 0,\cdots,m\right\} $.

Let $S:=\left\{ s\in\wp\left\{ 1,\dots,n\right\} \mid\#s=3\right\} $
and note that $\#S=\binom{n}{3}$.

For $s=\left\{ i,j,k\right\} \in S$ let $X_{s}$ denote the random variable that takes value $1$ if the edges $\left(i,j\right),\left(i,k\right),\left(j,k\right)$ are added
and takes value $0$ otherwise. Then $T_{n}=\sum_{s\in S}X_{s}$ so
that: $$\mathbb{E}T_{n}=\mathbb{E}\sum_{s\in S}X_{s}=\sum_{s\in S}\mathbb{E}X_{s}=\binom{n}{3}p^{3}$$

Likewise $T_{n}^{2}=\sum_{s\in S}\sum_{t\in S}X_{s}X_{t}$ so that: $$\mathbb{E}T_{n}^{2}=\sum_{s\in S}\sum_{t\in S}\mathbb{E}X_{s}X_{t}$$
and to find $\mathbb{E}X_{s}X_{t}$ we discern the following cases:

- $s\cap t=\varnothing$. We have $\#\left\{ \langle s,t\rangle\in S^{2}\mid s\cap t=\varnothing\right\} =\binom{n}{3}\binom{n-3}{3}$
  and $\mathbb{E}X_{s}X_{t}=p^{6}$.
- $\#\left(s\cap t\right)=1$. We have $\#\left\{ \langle s,t\rangle\in S^{2}\mid\#\left(s\cap t\right)=1\right\} =\binom{n}{3}3\binom{n-3}{2}$
  and $\mathbb{E}X_{s}X_{t}=p^{6}$.
- $\#\left(s\cap t\right)=2$. We have $\#\left\{ \langle s,t\rangle\in S^{2}\mid\#\left(s\cap t\right)=2\right\} =\binom{n}{3}3\binom{n-3}{1}$
  and $\mathbb{E}X_{s}X_{t}=p^{5}$.
- $s=t$. We have $\#\left\{ \langle s,t\rangle\in S^{2}\mid s=t\right\} =\binom{n}{3}$
  and $\mathbb{E}X_{s}X_{t}=p^{3}$.

This leads to $\mathbb{E}T_{n}^{2}=\binom{n}{3}p^{3}\left[\binom{n-3}{3}p^{3}+3\binom{n-3}{2}p^{3}+3\binom{n-3}{1}p^{2}+1\right]$
hence: $$\text{Var}T_{n}=\mathbb{E}T_{n}^{2}-\left(\mathbb{E}T_{n}\right)^{2}=\binom{n}{3}p^{3}\left[\binom{n-3}{3}p^{3}+3\binom{n-3}{2}p^{3}-\binom{n}{3}p^{3}+3\binom{n-3}{1}p^{2}+1\right]$$

Working this out we find: $$\text{Var}T_{n}=\binom{n}{3}p^{3}\left[p^{3}\left(8-3n\right)+3p^{2}\left(n-3\right)+1\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: I would start by considering a single vertex $v$. 
If we knew how many neighbors $v$ has (degree of $v$), then how many triangles does it participate in? It is a random variable, but what is its conditioned on that degree?

Of course, we do not know the degree of $v$. But again what is the degree distribution?

If we knew the expected number of triangles for a vertex $v$, then what is the expected number of triangles in the entire graph?